# change detection not getting triggered if a property of input object is changed in child component; property is bounded to [hidden]i in parent

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection, angular-changedetection

i am having a parent component in which i have a child component like this :

<child [field]='control' [hidden] = 'control.hide'>

initially control.hide = null
now, at a certain point in child component, i am changing hide to true based on certain condition.

but the change detection is not getting triggered in parent component and child component is not getting hidden although control.hide is two way bounded to hidden property.

just to check whether hide property of control object is getting changed to true or not, i just emitted an event and verified in parent component that control.hide is getting changed to true.

Comment: Please share a stackblitz with the issue replicated

Answer (score 0):

How do you use two way binding in your child component ?

Otherwise, in your child component, you can do something like :

```
@Input hidden;
@Output hiddenChange;

...
this.hiddenChange.emit(this.hidden);
...
```

In your parent component template :

```
<child [field]='control' [(hidden)] = 'control.hide'>
```

Comment: How do you use two way binding in your child component ?
control.hide is two way bounded to hidden property in parent component as :

<child [field]='control' [hidden] = 'control.hide'>